# Use lambda to modify references identified by a packed parameter?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, variadic-templates, generic-lambda

I'm trying to create a nice modify function of an entity's components in my WIP small "game framework". However I'm stuck at creating the function when trying to modify more than one component (using packed parameters)

This is my function for a single component, which works fine and behaves as I like

```cpp
template <typename C>
void mod_comp(Entity ent, std::function<void(C&)> cb) {
    auto& c = get_comp<C>(ent);
    return cb(c);
}

// Called like this
mng.mod_comp<Velocity>(ent, [](auto& vel) {
    // Modify velocity force value
    vel.f += 5;
});
```

When trying to create the function for multiple components I've found 2 problems that I cant figure out how to solve.

```cpp
template <typename... C>
void mod_comp(Entity ent, std::function<void(C...)> cb) {
    return cb(get_comp<C>(ent)...);
}

// Supposed to be called like this
mng.mod_comp<Velocity, Position>(ent, [](Velocity vel, Position pos) {
    pos.x += vel.f;
});
```

But this gives a "no match error" even tho the packed parameter `...C` (`Velocity, Position`) matches the parameters in the lambda (`Velocity, Position`). I can't figure out of to fix this.

**The main problem however** is if the lambda parameters can be simplified like the single mod function like this`([](auto& vel, auto& pos)` and also forward as references. I feel like this should be possible as nothing is unknown to the compiler but my C++ is limited.

Comment: Why are you using `forward_as_tuple`, when you're neither using `std::apply` nor a function taking a tuple? Have you tried calling `cb` as `cb(get_comp<C>(ent)...);`?

Comment: @alterigel you are correct it is unnecessary, tried `cb(get_comp<C>(ent)...)` however still gets "no matching function call"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some sneaky tricks to get the signature of the lambda and use it to get the components.

```
template <typename Class, typename... Params>
void mod_comp_helper(Entity ent, Class *obj, void (Class::*fun)(Params...) const) {
  (obj->*fun)(get_comp<std::decay_t<Params>>(ent)...);
}

// optional overload for mutable lambdas
template <typename Class, typename... Params>
void mod_comp_helper(Entity ent, Class *obj, void (Class::*fun)(Params...)) {
  (obj->*fun)(get_comp<std::decay_t<Params>>(ent)...);
}

template <typename Functor>
void mod_comp(Entity ent, Functor &&fun) {
  mod_comp_helper(ent, &fun, &std::decay_t<Functor>::operator());
}

// optional overload for function pointers
template <typename... Params>
void mod_comp(Entity ent, void(*fun)(Params...)) {
  fun(get_comp<std::decay_t<Params>(ent)>...);
}

int main() {
  mod_comp(ent, [](Velocity &vel, Position &pos) {
    // modify components
  });

  // you can use std::function if you want
  // although you probably don't need to
  std::function<void(Velocity &, Position &)> fun = [](Velocity &vel, Position &pos) {
    // modify components
  };

  mod_comp(ent, fun);

  // this calls the function pointer overload
  mod_comp(ent, +[](Velocity &vel, Position &pos) {
    // modify components
  });
}
```

A lambda expression is actually just syntax sugar for constructing a functor (an object with a call operator).

```
struct __anonymous_compiler_generated_class__ {
  void operator()(int i) const {
    // ...
  }
};

int main() {
  auto lambda = [](int i) {
    // ...
  };
  // above is sugar for this:
  auto functor = __anonymous_compiler_generated_class__{};
}
```

A lambda expression constructs a closure object. This object has an `operator()`. We can take the address of the call operator and deduce its signature. Then we just `std::decay_t` the parameter types to remove references and const-ness.

Another neat trick with lambdas is converting them to function pointers (which I showed in the first example). Non-capturing lambdas can be implicitly converted to function pointers. You can use a unary `+` or a `static_cast` to force this conversion. Here are a few more examples of that:

```
int main() {
  auto lambda = [](int i) {};
  void (*fnptr0)(int) = lambda;
  auto fnptr1 = +lambda;
  auto fnptr2 = static_cast<void(*)(int)>(lambda);

  int capture;
  auto capturing_lambda = [capture](int i) {};
  // compiler says no
  // auto fnptr3 = +capturing_lambda;
}
```

If you don't need capturing lambdas and can tolerate the unary `+` then you could just use the function pointer overload of `mod_comp` but for this, you probably want capturing lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but... taking in count that you explicit the variadic `C...` type list calling `mod_comp()`... what about passing the lambda simply as an executable, ignoring the connection with the `C...` list?

I mean... what about something as follows (caution: code not tested)

```
template <typename ... C, typename F>
void mod_comp (Entity ent, F && f)
 { return std::forward<F>(f)(get_comp<C>(ent)...); }
```

This should simply solve also your main problem, allowing you to pass a lambda (or a different callable) with a signature not exactly corresponding to `C...` so also with some `auto &` parameters.